# C++ Desktop Duplication API - Отрисовка курсора

Tags: c++, windows, directx

Использую Desktop Duplication API для захвата изображения с экрана. Всё работает за исключением отрисовки курсора - `IDXGISurface1::GetDC` возвращает код ошибки 0x887A0001 `DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL` (invalid parameter data). Так же первые 1-2 захваченных снимка иногда получаются пустые (заполненные черным цветом). Подскажите как исправить?

```
CComPtr<ID3D11Device> pDevice;
CComPtr<IDXGIOutputDuplication> pOutputDuplication;

BOOL Init()
{
    CComPtr<IDXGIFactory1> pDxgiFactory;
    CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> pDxgiAdapter;
    CComPtr<IDXGIOutput> pDxgiOutput;
    CComPtr<IDXGIOutput1> pDxgiOutput1;

    hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    CHECK_HR(CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)(&pDxgiFactory)));
    CHECK_HR(pDxgiFactory->EnumAdapters1(0, &pDxgiAdapter));
    CHECK_HR(pDxgiAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &pDxgiOutput));
    CHECK_HR(pDxgiOutput->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIOutput1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDxgiOutput1)));

    // Supported feature levels.
    const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL d3dFeatLvl;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* pImmediateContext = NULL;

    CHECK_HR(D3D11CreateDevice(pDxgiAdapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        0, 0, featureLevels, ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &pDevice,
        &d3dFeatLvl, &pImmediateContext));

    // Create desktop duplication.
    CHECK_HR(pDxgiOutput1->DuplicateOutput(pDevice, &pOutputDuplication));

    return TRUE;
}

HBITMAP CaptureScreenshot()
{
    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO DxgiFrameInfo;
    IDXGIResource* pDesktopResource;
    ID3D11Texture2D* pAcquiredDesktopImage;

AcquireFrame:
    if (FAILED(pOutputDuplication->AcquireNextFrame(5000, &DxgiFrameInfo, &pDesktopResource)))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (FAILED(pDesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), 
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pAcquiredDesktopImage))))
    {
        pDesktopResource->Release();
        return NULL;
    }

    pDesktopResource->Release();

    if (DxgiFrameInfo.LastPresentTime.QuadPart == 0)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
        pAcquiredDesktopImage->Release();
        pOutputDuplication->ReleaseFrame();
        goto AcquireFrame;
    }

    HBITMAP hBitmap = ExtractBitmap(hDC, pAcquiredDesktopImage, pDevice);

    pAcquiredDesktopImage->Release();
    pOutputDuplication->ReleaseFrame();
    return hBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование `IDXGISurface1::GetDC` предполагает выполнение пачки условий, описанных в разделе заметок в документации, как то, что swap chain создан с флагом `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_GDI_COMPATIBLE`, что контекст GDI из него ранее не извлекался и т.д. А вообще получаемая поверхность по идее не предназначена для рисования и странно использовать GDI только чтобы нарисовать курсор.

Далее, нельзя игнорировать содержимое `DxgiFrameInfo`, в т.ч. метки времени изменения потому что картинку имеет смысл читать только когда `LastPresentTime` не 0 и отличается от предыдущего значения.

Comment: Да, я прочитал, что там должны быть определённые условия. Странно просто, что `HRESULT` указывает на ошибку в параметре. Как можно тогда на `ID3D11Texture2D` нарисовать курсор мыши? Нужен не только рабочий, но и достаточно быстрый способ.

Comment: _"LastPresentTime не 0 и отличается от предыдущего значения"_ - Почему оно должно отличаться от предыдущего значения? Достаточно же просто проверить на равенство 0, чтобы понять были изменения или нет, и из этого делать вывод читать данные или подождать и проверить снова. Обновил код в вопросе, посмотрите.

Comment: @D.Stark Если `LastPresentTime` не отличается от предыдущего, то значит изображение не изменилось.  В `DxgiFrameInfo` также есть информация о том, виден ли аппаратный курсор (если нет, то и рисовать его нет необходимости). Ну а "достаточно быстрый" способ это сделать - рисовать курсор посредством ранее созданного устройства directx. Ну а если потом это все равно передается на сторону CPU, то тогда самостоятельно отрисовать его в массиве пикслей.

Comment: _"Если LastPresentTime не отличается от предыдущего, то значит изображение не изменилось"_ - Но ведь вызов `AcquireNextFrame` автоматически обнуляет `LastPresentTime`, разве нет? _"В DxgiFrameInfo также есть информация о том, виден ли аппаратный курсор"_ - Эта информация так же есть в поле `CURSORINFO.flags`, но это пригодно если рисовать курсор через GDIшные `GetCursorInfo` и `DrawCursorEx`. _"рисовать курсор посредством ранее созданного устройства directx"_ - Как это можно сделать? Можете накинуть несколько интерфейсов и функций, которые можно для этого использовать?

Comment: @D.Stark Вызов `AcquireNextFrame` позволяет получить новое значение поля `LastPresentTime`. Для рисования курсора посредством directx необходимо составить графический конвейер, написать шейдеры и запустить его.